# Does there exist a constant $C>0$ such that for all simple functions $f$, $\int_1^\infty|f|\leq C(\int_1^\infty|f|^p)^{1/p}$?

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces, holder-inequality, simple-functions

I'm trying to solve the following problem.

Let $p\in(0,\infty)$ be fixed. Determine, with justification, whether the following statement is true or false.

There exists a constant $C>0$ such that for all simple functions $f:[1,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$, $$\int_1^\infty|f(x)|dx\leq C\left(\int_1^\infty|f(x)|^pdx\right)^{1/p}.$$

I think the statement is false. My thought is to proceed by supposing it is true. But I can't seem to arrive at a contradiction. Any hints regarding this are greatly appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose such an inequality holds. Take $f=\chi_E$. We get $\mu (E)\leq C\mu(E)^{1/p}$ or $(\mu (E))^{1-\frac  1p} \leq C$. Is is easy tpo get a  contradiciton  by letting $\mu (E) \to 0$ or $\mu(E) \to \infty$.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that it is true, for any $f\in L^{p}$, choose a sequence $(\varphi_{n})$ of simple functions such that $\varphi_{n}\rightarrow f$ in $L^{p}$ and $\varphi_{n}(x)\rightarrow f(x)$ a.e.

Fatou's lemma implies that
\begin{align*}
\int|f(x)|\leq\liminf\int|\varphi_{n}(x)|dx\leq C\liminf\left(\int|\varphi_{n}(x)|^{p}\right)^{1/p}\leq C\left(\int|f(x)|^{p}\right)^{1/p}.
\end{align*}

For $p>1$, choose $f(x)=\dfrac{1}{x^{\eta}}$, where $0<\eta<1$ and $\eta p>1$, then
\begin{align*}
\int_{1}^{\infty}|f(x)|^{p}dx<\infty
\end{align*}
but
\begin{align*}
\int_{1}^{\infty}|f(x)|dx=\infty.
\end{align*}

Comment: For $0<p<1$, it is a matter of $\int_{1}^{\infty}|f(x)|^{q}dx\leq C\int_{1}^{\infty}|f(x)|dx$ for $q>1$. This is also false, consider $f(x)=\frac{1}{(x-1)^{\eta}}\chi_{[1,2]}(x)$ for an appropriate $0<\eta<1$ such that $\eta q>1$.

Comment: could you explain how $\lim inf \|\varphi_n\|_p\leq C \|f\|_p$. I can tell you used the triangle inequality then the smallness of $\|f-\varphi_{n}\|_p$ but limit inferior is super additive ...so ?

Comment: As I have by the assumption that $\varphi_{n}\rightarrow f$ in $L^{p}$, then $\|f-\varphi_{n}\|_{L^{p}}\rightarrow 0$, so $\|\varphi_{n}\|_{p}=\|\varphi_{n}-f+f\|_{p}\leq C_{p}(\|\varphi_{n}-f\|_{p}+\|f\|_{p})$, now taking $n\rightarrow\infty$, the left should be taken as $\liminf$. Note that for $0<p<1$, the $C_{p}$ is something like $2^{p}$, but then for $p\geq 1$ we simply take $C_{p}=1$.

Comment: Okay.  Yes. If $a_{n}\leq b_{n}+c_{n}$, $b_{n}\rightarrow b$, $c_{n}\rightarrow c$.  then  $\liminf a_{n}\leq \liminf (b_n+c_n)=\lim(b_n+c_n)=\lim b_n+\lim c_n$ which is what you used. Thanks